# Proper/secure method for users to add notes to a mySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, security, database-design

Thanks for reading. **Before you read**  - I am using **PHP & mySQL**

I'm creating a simple web app where users will be accessing historical pricing for various products but will need to have their own unique notes about different products.

There are roughly 100,000 products, each with their own table containing 50 to 100 rows at any given time.

I have no experience with database design so I need some help!

**1)** What is the best way to store user notes for these products? Would it be best practice to create a table for each product containing notes generated by every user?

**2)** Assuming a product is added, and no table has been previously generated for it, would it be considered 'secure' if I allow for dynamic table creation? (When I say dynamic, I mean within the PHP a check is performed and if no table exists, a table is created.)

**2a)** While I do not anticipate any form of hacking, I am concerned that the ability to create tables provides too much access. Is it possible to allow for table creation but restrict the mySQL user from other functions such as drop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please break your question down into single, specific questions. I'm sure you'll find a lot of them have already been asked several times with very good answers too on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are roughly 100,000 products, each with their own table containing 50 to 100 rows at any given time.

Creating a separate table for each individual object is almost always an anti-pattern.

Fix your design and store all products in the same table, and as a consequence you'll be able to model your other requirements much more naturally. For example:

[image]